# Getting User Roles from Username

Tags: user-management, membership-provider

How do I get User Roles based on Username?

```
UserRoles roles = user.Roles;
string role = roles.GetEnumerator().ToString();
```

If I have a user, I can get it like this. But how do I get the roles when all I have is a Username?

Answer (score 7):

To get a user by a username you can use :

```
public class UserRepository
{
    public static User GetUser(string domainName, string userName)
    {
       if (User.Exists(domainName + @"\" + userName))
       {
           return User.FromName(domainName + @"\" + userName, true);
       }
       return null;
    }
}
```

To get a user roles you can use

```
  Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user = UserRepository.GetUser("yourdomain","youruserName");

  if (user==null) return;

  var rolesList = user.Roles.ToList();

  foreach(var role in rolesList)
  {
     var roleName = role.DisplayName;
     var roleDomain = role.Domain;
     // you have all the properties of a role in role object
  }
```

Comment: Nice! Small comment... since your example above can return null for a user, you probably should have a check before accessing user.Roles

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to extract a list of users and their roles into a report.

```powershell
$users = Get-User -Filter * | Where-Object { $_.Roles.Count -gt 0 }

$records = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach($user in $users) {
    $record = [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Username" = $user.Name
        "Roles" = ($user.Roles | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","
    }
    $records.Add($record) > $null
}

$records
```